# Is there a way I can find a div element by both its css 'left' and 'top' attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of div that look like this below:

```
<div class="blockattribute" id="1" style="background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217); left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
```

I have a bunch of these on a grid and as part of my floodfill algorithm, I want to select adjacent grids by `left` and `top` as my x and y coordinates. So far I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. Does anyone have a recommendation as to how to accomplish this?

From a stackoverflow question I have tried the following selector:

```
$("div['style=left: 0px; top:0px;']");
```

I think this is close but I get this error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div['style=left: 0px; top:0px;']
```

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11396681/1627271) helps..

Comment: Hey @choz, thanks for the link but this is not quite what I'm looking for. I was able to get the information from the method and the result yielded this:

`block1[0].getBoundingClientRect();`

`ClientRect {top: 8, right: 306, bottom: 28, left: 286, width: 20…}`

That's not exactly what I was going for because when I want to find adjacent square (right,left,top,bottom) I want to be able to just add pixels to to and left and grab the element from there.

Comment: I've added my answer but  I'd suggest to go with Evan's one by using `filter` function since I think it's cleaner.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First off, your code `$("div['style=left: 0px; top:0px;']");` is syntactically invalid. It needs quote around the attribute value only like this:

```
$('div[style="left: 0px; top:0px;"]');
```

That being said, it still won't get you the desired result since your inline style would have to *match exactly*.

To get a bit closer you can use wildcard attribute selector to get part of the inline style like this, though it's really going to be very finicky and so much as a single whitespace will cause this to fail.

```js
$('div[style*="left: 0px; top: 0px"]').html('test345');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blockattribute" id="1" style="background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217); left: 0px; top: 0px;">test 123</div>
```

A bit more on this here: https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/#rel-anywhere.

Comment: Actually it looks like it kinda should work but what if there is something between the `left` and `top` declarations?

Comment: I replaced div with `blockattribute` and I got it to work.

Comment: @KodosJohnson - this would fail in that case.  Like I said, it's going to be very finicky and unstable.  On the other hand, if your styles are extremely predictable it could still work.

Answer (score 3):

how about something like:

```
$(".blockattribute").filter(function(ind,el){return $(el).offset().left == your_value && $(el).offset().top == your_value})
```

or if you are intent on using css values, you can do something like:

```
$(".blockattribute").filter(function(ind,el){return $(el).css("left") == your_value+"px" && $(el).css("top") == your_value2+"px"})
```

Comment: Hey Evan, I liked your answer but for the `your_value` part I tried placing a sample coordinate like `20` and `0` and I got an empty array. Also I tried `20px` and `0px' but still got nothing. Am I missing something?

Comment: `.offset().top` and `.offset().left` calculates the coordinates relative to the document. I think it would be better to use `.css('top')` and `.css('left')`. Since the OP is asking about the top and left css property values.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Personally, I'd rather use `offset()` than `css`. Since jquery implemented it by using `getBoundingClientRect` which I assume is the correct approach based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element/11396681#11396681)

Comment: @DanRubio offset is relative to the page, if you want css values, use .css() as KodosJohnson suggested

Answer (score 2):

You're selecting it wrong. One way to achieve this is to iterate the `divs` and check its `left` and `top` value.

```js
$(function() {
  var selectDiv = function(left, top) {
    var $arrDiv = [];
    $('div.blockattribute').each(function(i, v) {
      var $div = $(v);
      $arrDiv.push($div);
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < $arrDiv.length; i++) {
      var $div = $arrDiv[i];
      var offset = $div.offset();
      if (offset.left === left && offset.top === top) {
        return $div;
      }
    }
    
    return null;
  }
  
  var $selectedDiv = selectDiv(20, 20);
  console.log($selectedDiv.attr('id'));
});
```

```css
.blockattribute {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blockattribute" id="1" style="background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217); left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
<div class="blockattribute" id="2" style="background-color: rgb(17, 17, 17); left: 20px; top: 20px;"></div>
<div class="blockattribute" id="3" style="background-color: rgb(121, 121, 121); left: 40px; top: 40px;"></div>
```

***Note:*** Check Evan's answer which has cleaner solution than this.